# What is the difference between these fuctions?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two way of defining a method?

```
 var Todo = {};
    Todo.abc = function(){
    }
```

and

```
function abc(){
}
```

Comment: One is a function and one is a variable assignment

Comment: Try some [rubber duck problem solving](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). To answer your question, they're actually both similar in that they have a letter **`n`** in the word `function`, unlike your title. Actually, your question is malformed--you cannot ask "what is the difference between these two way [sic] of defining a method", because they are not both methods. I'd start off with learning correct terminology (for example, `abc` is not a "keyword") and take it from there.

Comment: @scrappedcola, variable assignment? I thought i added a function value to the abc keyword of Todo object

Comment: `abc` is just a variable in an object. You are thinking in more java terms and that often does not directly apply to JS. The variable assignment is just assigning an anonymous function to the variable `abc`. Functions are just objects that are assignable like any other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is an [anonymous function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), stored in the `abc` property. These are not [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting).

The second is a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). It has a `name` property and it is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

> The main difference between a function expression and a function statement is the function name, which can be omitted in function expressions to create anonymous functions.
>
> Function expressions in JavaScript are not hoisted, unlike function declarations. You can't use function expressions before you define them:

Answer (score 0):

First is a Todo property, second is a global function.
In fact, in order to call the first one you have to write

```
Todo.abc();
```

Note that Todo.abc = 'Hello' will overwrite instance property.

Comment: if I create the global function would not it clutter the global namespace? Should i avoid defining global methods?

Comment: @Raaz it isn't a completly true statement that `abc()` is a global function. It is a global function in the context of the current scope which might not  be the global scope.

Comment: You can create a your own namespace upon global namespace. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript